# How to read an excel with more than 16 characters per cells with Python ?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I've an issue with my excel file. In the first colums there are dates with more than 16 characters (05/06/2017 14:55:12). There is a gap between date and hours. When I read the file and I try to split the first column it does not work. I use the library pandas
`data=pd.read_csv('v11_11_2016.csv', sep='[ ,]', skiprows=7, engine='python')
izi=data['Date']`[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TXKx.png)

With this code I don't get the seconds.. it splits but it only keeps in memory the firts 16 characters. 
Any help would be very appreciated
Thanks 
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how your csv-file actually looks because you didn't include the source of it in your post, but I think the problem you're facing is the following:

The issue seems to be the `sep='[ ,]'` argument, which is a regular expression that will cause splits on commas **and spaces**. Try using `sep=','` instead and see how that changes the output of your program.

**EDIT:**

If you include a sample of your data, it will be easier to tell which kind of separators you'll have to use. To do this, open your csv with a regular text editor and attach the text to your post.